# Why does this work? Bitwise AND comparison, Access 2010 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I wanted a clean way to distinguish between regular tables and system table while iterating through the `TableDefs` collection.
I came across this example in an MS KB article, and while it's poor, there was one piece that looked interesting.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210362

So I wrote this:

```
Function ListTables()

Dim objDB As DAO.Database
Dim objTdf As DAO.TableDef

Set objDB = CurrentDb()

For Each objTdf In objDB.TableDefs
    If objTdf.Attributes And dbSystemObject Then
    Else
        Debug.Print objTdf.Name
    End If
Next objTdf

Set objDB = Nothing

End Function
```

Frankly, I don't know how/why the comparison of `objTdf.Attributes` And `dbSystemObject` works. Can someone explain?

Attributes for system tables appears to be -2147483648 and `dbSystemObject`'s value is -2147483646.
Thoughts?

Comment: -2147483648 is one 1 and 31 zeros in binary. -2147483646 seems to be 31 ones and one 0. They have one 1 bit in common.

Comment: Converting a negative number to binary isn't the same as for positive numbers.  This page shows 3 ways to do it, vba should use one of them : https://www.ehow.com/how_5124016_convert-negative-numbers-binary.html

Comment: Essentially `objTdf.Attributes` is a collection of individual bits where each bit represents a different property, like is it a system table, is it an attached table, etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing) for the general idea

Comment: @SteveK I believe you are representing -2147483646 incorrectly - a 2's complement representation is almost surely what's used, 0x80000002. Whereas -2147483648 is 0x80000000 like you said. This almost makes sense to me. I would expect the attributes value to just be 0x00000000 and the dbSystemObject value to be 0x00000002.

Comment: I think you're right, but I don't remember how it's done. If the highest bit is 1, maxint32+1 is subtracted from the rest, so that a full set of 1s equals -1, right ?

Comment: @JKillian Yes, your gut seems good to me. The values might actually be 0 and 2.

Comment: And agreed Steve, for the sake of what's important here, thinking of the values as 0 and 2 is conceptually solid and useful. I don't know for sure how VBA stores integers and interprets them as true or false, but probably not really worth looking into haha

Comment: One easy way to do two's complement is "flip the bits and add 1". So 1 (0x00000001) <-> -1 (0xFFFFFFFF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bitwise And, which means that each bit in the result will be 1 if the corresponding bit in each of the original values is 1.  `dbSystemObject` is presumably a power of two, which means that it has one bit set.  The result of the bitwise And will have that same bit set if the corresponding bit is set in `objTdf.Attributes`.  If the result has any bits set then, as a Boolean, it will be `True`, otherwise it will be `False`.  If the table is a system table then that bit will be set in `objTdf.Attributes` and therefore in the result too.

That numeric value for `objTdf.Attributes` is a combination of powers of 2, one of which is equal to `dbSystemObject`.

You can think of the binary representation of numbers as a series of Boolean values, where 1 is `True` and 0 is `False`.  In that way, a 32-bit number can represent 32 Boolean values.  Attributes are often represented that way.  As an example, let's say that you use an 8-bit number to represent 8 attributes: First, Second, Third, ..., Eighth.  If you wanted to represent a situation where the attributes First, Third and Seventh were `True` and all others were `False` then, in binary, that would be 01000101.  That number is 69.  Now let's say that you want to determine whether the Fifth attribute is `True` for that value.  You would perform a bitwise And to produce a result where each bit is set only the corresponding bit is set in both arguments:

```
01000101 (69)
00010000 (16)
-------- And
00000000  (0)
```

As you can see, there are no positions where both arguments have the same bit set so all bits are 0 in the result.  Convert the result to a Boolean and you get `False`, because zero is considered `False`. That means that the original value does not have the Fifth attribute set to `True`.

Now let's say that you want to determine whether the Third attribute is `True`:

```
01000101 (69)
00000100  (4)
-------- And
00000100  (4)
```

The two arguments both the bit at the third position set so that bit is set in the result.  Convert the result to a Boolean and you get `True`, because any value other than zero is considered `True`. That means that the original value does have the Third attribute set to `True`.

Comment: That sounds completely plausible as your answer is completely over my head! I'll have to study up on bitwise operator and comparison. I've only used AND, OR in a more conventional manner. Thank you!

Comment: I've added a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Much appreciated, that helps a great deal and illuminates things more fully. In more simplistic terms I think I see how it converts the values to bits so a binary comparison can be made resulting in a True or False answer (Something the IF THEN ELSE would expect). Thank you.

Its my hope to understand it so I know when and how to use a similar comparison in the future and not just copy/paste from example code. I should know how and when to use this, whether its VBA or anything else. Thanks.